# laravel register routes like Auth::routes

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to make a package but i am stuck at registering routes.

I am trying to register route just like Auth::routes();

```
public static function routes(array $options = [])
{
    if (! static::$app->providerIsLoaded(UiServiceProvider::class)) {
        throw new RuntimeException('In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.');
    }

    static::$app->make('router')->auth($options);
}
```

Where can i get $app?
it seems that $app->make('router')->auth($options) is the command that registers route..
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: that is specifically for those auth routes ... that isn't how routes are registered in general (just how auth does it) ... `$app` is the application container, that code you have above is in a Facade and Facade's have the container bound to them, so if you are writing that method on a Facade you have access to `$app` the same way

Comment: this is actually not a good example as this particular Facade is just basically just an alias for the `Route::auth()` method itself anyway ... that is what is actually be called here ... you won't have to do this type of thing in your own package or facade